# Download to smb share silently fails

Tags: mount, nautilus, firefox, samba

I'm using the PPA version of Firefox on Jammy (/usr/bin/firefox). If I mount an authenticated SMB share in Nautilus I can read and write to it without issue. If I download a file in Firefox and try to save the file to the share, it will close the dialog without error, but the file isn't saved to the share. If I save the file locally but drag it over, then it works.

I launched Firefox using the shell to look for error messages but there aren't any. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong - I was in fact using the snap version of Firefox. The .deb version does not have this problem.